# Spinner not using onItemSelected method in API 23

Tags: java, android, spinner

I use the following code, I've tried to implement a spinner within my app:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //region UI declaration
    Button HelloWorldbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button ClientVersionbtn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Button VerifyUserID = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Spinner spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final TextView spnSelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LocationText);
    //endregion

    //region Spinner creation
    List<String> spinnerArray =  StartSpinner();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
    spn.setAdapter(adapter);

    spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            spnSelection.setText(item.toString());
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

        }
    });
    //endregion

    HelloWorldbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onHelloWorld(v);
        }
    });

    ClientVersionbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClientVersion(v);
        }
    });

    VerifyUserID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onVerifyUser(v);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

The code compiles just and runs. However, when I select an item from the spinner, it does not run the `onItemSelected` method. I used the debugger and no errors appear in the **logcat** and no exceptions are thrown. I have tried custom adapters and custom `onItemSelected` listeners but I still have the same issue. My current thought is that this might be an issue with API 23 but I haven't been able to confirm.

I'm also open to any alternatives to using a spinner as it does not seem to be the easiest widget to maintain or implement. I'd like it to be as simple as possible for anyone that has to maintain it in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set a dropdown view for the adapter.

Your implementation should be like this.

```
List<String> spinnerArray =  StartSpinner();
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spn.setAdapter(adapter );
spn.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        spnSelection.setText(item.toString());
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

    }
});
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I have implemented this change but it is still not going to the onItemSelected method

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because of you did not attached **dropdownView** to the spinner.

```
   final ArrayAdapter<String> = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spn.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try the code above. 
Cheers!

Comment: I have implemented this change but I'm still having issues getting to the onItemSelected method

Comment: Are you sure? `onItemSelected` is not getting called? because you must be checking if the value is setting or not. Possibly you are getting empty value of `Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);`

Comment: I have the break points set within the method and they are never called.

Comment: Set dropdownView to adapter and check what happens! I've edited the code.